# Is Entity framework 4.0 is generating effective queries?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am using entity framework 1.0 and not satisfied with the generated queries by it. Even a small query length is more then 100 line after generation. Can any one update that in entity framework this issue has been resolved or not?

Thanks in advance,
Kamal Kant Pansari

Comment: You said EF 4.0 in title and 1.0 in post. Which are you using? Also, I would run performance tests before judging the queries simply by eyeballing them.

Comment: Does your DB server reject long or non-pretty queries, or is there an actual problem that you'd like to mention?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**

Here are some articles on using your own stored procedure in the Entity Framework.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bindeshv/archive/2008/11/20/using-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2009/11/25/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

**EDIT**

I haven't done direct comparisons of Entity Framework 1 vs 4, but I would hope that their queries have gotten better.

**ORIGINAL**

The Entity Framework offers convenience as a trade off for performance. If you don't like what the Entity Framework has generated, you can override and provide your own stored procedure.